# Apps (e.g. Camera) disappeared from File Picker in new Edge version

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, camera, uwp

With Edge, it used to be possible to launch UWP apps (that registered as File Open Picker) through the file picker. We used this feature to launch a camera custom app (that had full access to the device camera) and upload images to a web app.

With the new Edge version this seems this is no longer possible. Those apps are gone from the file picker!

Old Edge version 42.17134.1098.0:
[image]

New Edge version 87.0.664.75:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been using the old version of Edge, called Legacy Edge,
which as a UWP app itself had no problem running other UWP apps.
Unfortunately, this version was choke-full with bugs and couldn't adapt
to newer standards, so was ditched by Microsoft.
Microsoft has now embarrassed the opposition,
and its new Microsoft Edge version is based on Google's Chromium.
Unfortunately, it doesn't support UWP.

Up to Windows 10 version 20H2, it was possible to run the two
Edge versions, as described in the article
[Access Microsoft Edge Legacy after installing the new version of Microsoft Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-access-old-edge).
However, starting with version 20H2, Microsoft Edge Legacy is disappearing.

A Chrome extension that can also be installed on the new Microsoft Edge is
supposed to allow invoking UWP apps. You may try it at
[UWP Companion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uwp-companion/egfgdliklfgpmdjfofbmhmoejdhehani).

If that extension does not help,
a way to force Windows to keep Microsoft Edge Legacy alive in Windows 20H2
is detailed in the article
[How to Restore Old Legacy Microsoft Edge Browser After Installing New Edge in Windows 10](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-restore-old-legacy-microsoft-edge-browser-after-installing-new-edge-in-windows-10/).

This method involves registry changes, and may require uninstalling the new
Microsoft Edge. See also the article
[How to Uninstall New Microsoft Edge in Windows 10? Uninstall Button Grayed Out or Disabled](https://www.askvg.com/fix-how-to-uninstall-new-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10-uninstall-button-grayed-out-or-disabled/)
for when you already upgraded to version 20H2.

However, while the above fixes may work for now, Microsoft will continue in its
crusade against Microsoft Edge Legacy, so their life-time may be limited
and their effect would become unpredictable.
I would recommend finding other methods of launching your UWP app than from
Edge.

Comment: I once uninstalled Chromium Edge using the installer method and I had some major issues.  It's uninstalled but it's next to impossible to reinstall it , since eventually, Legacy Edge in March 2020 is unsupported entirely.